# Speech Transcription: Narrowband or Broadband?

Tags: javascript, ibm-watson

Using IBM Watson they have the option to do speaker recognition (Person 1, Person 2) etc.

This only works with a Narrowband model.  It would be cool to have but not at the expense of an accurate transcript.  Will choosing the narrowband model decrease accuracy?  I'm transcribing movie dialog.

Answer (score -1):

If you want speaker recognition, then Narrowband is your only option at the moment.

The [documentation says](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/output.shtml#speaker_labels):

> The speaker labels feature is currently beta functionality that is
>   available for US English, Spanish, and Japanese narrowband models
>   only.

which sound to me like it may be rolled out to Broadband models in the future. If that happens, the Broadband models would then be more appropriate for movie dialog.

I wouldn't expect Narrowband to have significantly decreased accuracy; the main knock against it is that it requires more work (by the Watson service) to produce the same quality of results.

You could always try transcribing a clip both ways (without speaker_labels) and compare the results to see for yourself if the accuracy is any different.